# Multiple values in single column of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that I'm parsing from XML to a pandas DataFrame. The XML data roughly looks like this:

```
<tracks>
  <track name="trackname1" variants="1,2,3,4,5">
    <variant var="1,2,3">
      <leg time="21:23" route_id="5" stop_id="103" serial="1"/>
      <leg time="21:26" route_id="5" stop_id="17" serial="2"/>
      <leg time="21:30" route_id="5" stop_id="38" serial="3"/>
      <leg time="20:57" route_id="8" stop_id="101" serial="1"/>
      <leg time="21:01" route_id="8" stop_id="59" serial="2"/>
      ...
    </variant>
    <variant var="4,5">
      ... more leg elements
    </variant>
  </track>
  <track name="trackname2" variants="1,2,3,4,5,6,7">
    <variant var="1">
      ... more leg elements
    </variant>
    <variant var="2,3,4,5,7">
      ... more leg elements
    </variant>
  </track>
</tracks>
```

I'm importing this into pandas because I need to be able to join this data with other DataFrames and I need to be able to query for stuff like: "get all legs of variant 1 for route_id 5".

I'm trying to figure out how I would do this in a pandas DataFrame. Should I make a DataFrame that would look something like this:

```
track_name     variants  time     route_id  stop_id  serial
"trackname1"   "1,2,3"   "21:23"  "5"       "103"    "1"
"trackname1"   "1,2,3"   "21:26"  "5"       "17"     "2"
...
"trackname1"   "4,5"     "21:20"  "5"       "103"    "1"
...
"trackname2"   "1"       "20:59"  "3"       "45"     "1"
... you get the point
```

If this is the way to go, how would I (efficiently) extract for example "all rows for variant 3 on route_id 5"? Note that this should give me all the rows that have 3 in the variant column list, not just the rows that *only* have "3" in the variants column.

Is there a different way of constructing the DataFrame that would make this easier? Should I be using something other than pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have enough memory, your task will be more easily accomplished if your DataFrame held one variant per row:

```
track_name     variants  time     route_id  stop_id  serial
"trackname1"   1         "21:23"         5      103       1
"trackname1"   2         "21:23"         5      103       1
"trackname1"   3         "21:23"         5      103       1
"trackname1"   1         "21:26"         5       17       2
"trackname1"   2         "21:26"         5       17       2
"trackname1"   3         "21:26"         5       17       2
...
"trackname1"   4         "21:20"         5      103       1
"trackname1"   5         "21:20"         5      103       1
...
"trackname2"   1         "20:59"         3       45       1
```

Then you could find "all rows for variant 3 on route_id 5 with

```
df.loc[(df['variants']==3) & (df['route_id']==5)]
```

If you pack many variants into one row, such as

```
"trackname1"   "1,2,3"   "21:23"  "5"       "103"    "1"
```

then you could find such rows using

```
df.loc[(df['variants'].str.contains("3")) & (df['route_id']=="5")]
```

*assuming* that the variants are always single digits. If there are also 2-digit variants like "13" or "30", then you would need to pass a more complicated regex pattern to `str.contains`.

Alternatively, you could use `apply` to split each variant on commas:

```
df['variants'].apply(lambda x: "3" in x.split(','))
```

but this is very inefficent since you would now be calling a Python function
once for every row, and doing string splitting and a test for membership in a
list compared to a vectorized integer comparision.

Thus, to avoid possibly complicated regex or a relatively slow call to `apply`, I think your best bet is to build the DataFrame with one integer variant per row.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I was hoping it wouldn't be :-/ I can avoid the string manipulation by doing that when I'm parsing the data and instead of inserting a string "1,2,3,5" into the variant column I'd split it during parsing and insert a list or a tuple instead. That would be much more efficient but still a little borked somehow. I was really hoping that I would be able to have some sort of "multidimensional columns" or whatever you'd call them.