# Can tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature handle categorical features with multiple inputs within one column?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm just using Tensorflow and its tf.learn api to create and train a DNNRegressor model. I have an integer feature column that is multivalent (I can have more than one integer value in that column for each row) and I use tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature for this feature column.

now my question is what is the right delimeter for the multivalent feature column in csv file.
for example supose I have a csv that col2 is multivalent feature and its not one hot feature:

```
  1, 2, 1:2:3:4, 5
  2, 1, 4:5, 6
```

as you see I use ':' for seperating integer feature valuse in col2 but it seems its not right and I got this error while running DNNRegressor with declaring this feature column as tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature:

```
 'Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType string not in list of allowed 
  values: int32, int64, float32, float64'.
```

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/sparse_column_with_integerized_feature) is for `int32` or `int64` values only, so it won't work exactly as you want.

But `tensorflow` supports multi-dimensions in numerical columns, so you can work with [`tf.feature_column.numeric_column`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/numeric_column) and specify the `shape` that you have. Note that tensorflow will expect that all of those shapes are the same, so you'll need to pad all of your values to a common shape.

The colon `':'` delimeter is fine for multivalent columns, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792852/multiple-values-in-single-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe) how to read multiple values into a `DataFrame` with pandas (the question is about XML, but the same works for CSV). This data frame you can pass into `model.train()` function as `input_fn`.