# Read text file data using python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a text file containing a number of columns and rows, with a variety of data types. I would like to read the file in python and plot the values by selecting the columns.
My file looks like this:

```
    time        column1        column2        column3        column4        column5        column6        column7 
 100.035   6.667252E+00  -4.106210E+00  -1.577542E-02   4.090584E+00  -3.699584E-01  -6.998253E-02  -6.699544E-01 
 100.075   6.776713E+00  -4.347899E+00  -1.791951E-02   4.329726E+00  -3.699584E-01  -6.998253E-02  -6.699544E-01 
 100.115   6.806808E+00  -4.451121E+00  -1.886022E-02   4.432934E+00  -3.699584E-01  -6.998253E-02  -6.699544E-01 
 100.155   6.826516E+00  -4.534202E+00  -1.924360E-02   4.513488E+00  -3.699584E-01  -6.998253E-02  -6.699544E-01 
 100.195   6.890967E+00  -4.962194E+00  -1.946191E-02   4.943943E+00  -3.699584E-01  -6.998253E-02  -6.699544E-01 
 100.235   6.961544E+00  -5.430468E+00  -1.924892E-02   5.409640E+00  -3.699584E-01  -6.998253E-02  -6.699544E-01
```

I tried reading the file as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792852/multiple-values-in-single-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732771/reading-columns-of-a-txt-file-on-python/54732936) and also tried some pattern-based delimited codes as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216573/reading-specific-columns-from-a-text-file-in-python/30216631). So far the output from the code below has all the columns cramped-up at `first_columns` as listed `values`.

```
import csv
with open ('mps50.txt', 'r') as f:
     first_column = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')]
```

But `first_column` is a list and I can't think of how to use this further that can help me plot the values. Can you guide me on how to look to do this? Some samples or a link would be helpful.
[image: first_column looks like this.]

Comment: you can do as follows 

```python
import csv


with open ('mps50.txt', 'r') as f:
     data= csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
     first_col, other_cols = data[0], data[1:]
```
So now you have your first column and the data representing it, use those lists to Plot

Comment: What happens when you print(first_column)?

Comment: @quamrana I see the columns in a nice way as I would expect.

Comment: @ElSheikh doesn't solve the problem, `first_col` now has the column names, `other_cols` is the rest of data row wise.

Comment: @quamrana please see edits

Comment: @SamAct ``headers = next(data)  # to skip 1st line` and then loop on your data
```python

first_cols, other_cols = [], []
for row in data:
     first_col.append(row[0])
     other_cols.append(row[1:])
```

Comment: @ElSheikh ok that takes me further, whats next?

Comment: Solved? It's look like you have irregular spacing. I will propose an answer using pyparsing.

Comment: @Raphael not even near solved.

Comment: Working on it. Do you need the header? Or only the values?

Comment: @SamAct What kind of graphs you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `pandas`:

- Use `pandas.read_csv` to read the data

  - This assumes the data as shown, in a `txt` file, with spaces as separators.
- Use `matplotlib` to plot

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\\s+')

# df view
    time   column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7
 100.035  6.667252 -4.106210 -0.015775  4.090584 -0.369958 -0.069983 -0.669954
 100.075  6.776713 -4.347899 -0.017920  4.329726 -0.369958 -0.069983 -0.669954
 100.115  6.806808 -4.451121 -0.018860  4.432934 -0.369958 -0.069983 -0.669954
 100.155  6.826516 -4.534202 -0.019244  4.513488 -0.369958 -0.069983 -0.669954
 100.195  6.890967 -4.962194 -0.019462  4.943943 -0.369958 -0.069983 -0.669954
 100.235  6.961544 -5.430468 -0.019249  5.409640 -0.369958 -0.069983 -0.669954
```

### plot the data:

- There are many options for plotting the data.

  - Following are a few simple examples

```py
# all columns
plt.plot(df['time'], df.iloc[:, 1:], marker='o')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
# specific column
plt.plot(df['time'], df['column1'], marker='o')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

- With `seaborn`

```py
import seaborn as sns

# set the index
df_ind = df.set_index('time')

sns.lineplot(data=df_ind, dashes=False, markers=True)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very simple and elegant. How did you decide on the 'sep' when you read the csv?

Comment: Just experience.  I haven’t had tab sep work as well as looking for one or more white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

## Using PyParsing

Just to give you an alternative in case you have non-uniform separation of elements, but I would go with pandas in this case.

```
import pyparsing as pp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ifile = open('test.csv','r')
csv_file = ifile.read()
ifile.close()

EOL = pp.LineEnd().suppress()
number = pp.pyparsing_common.number

ncols = 8

row = ( number*ncols + EOL)

results = []

for t, s, e in row.scanString(csv_file):
    results.append(t.asList())

print(results)


[[100.035, 6.667252, -4.10621, -0.01577542, 4.090584, -0.3699584, -0.06998253, -0.6699544],
 [100.075, 6.776713, -4.347899, -0.01791951, 4.329726, -0.3699584, -0.06998253, -0.6699544],
 [100.115, 6.806808, -4.451121, -0.01886022, 4.432934, -0.3699584, -0.06998253, -0.6699544],
 [100.155, 6.826516, -4.534202, -0.0192436, 4.513488, -0.3699584, -0.06998253, -0.6699544],
 [100.195, 6.890967, -4.962194, -0.01946191, 4.943943, -0.3699584, -0.06998253, -0.6699544],
 [100.235, 6.961544, -5.430468, -0.01924892, 5.40964, -0.3699584, -0.06998253, -0.6699544]]
```